# SCNNode.position STATIC?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, scenekit

So I have an object that is getting moved via its physicsBody and a physicsField (spring). The spring is connected to an object that is constantly rotating using a SCNAction.

For some reason, whenever I use the gestureRecognizer (tapping the first object), (which works, as I am having the object glow when it is tapped), I NSLog the position of both objects, and both come out as having the same coordinates (0,0,0) and (0,5,0) which are the starting positions, but no more. What am I missing? Why am I not getting the actual coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try node.presentationNode.position